# I have a set of 4 JFrames with checkboxes in them and I would like to know how to merge them all into one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, multiple-instances

It is a project and I am an import store with many different products. The store consists of 4 different categories of products: Toys, Videogames, Apparel, and Books. Whenever I run the main program it only runs one of the four. I could just put the information from each into one of the products but I want them to keep the titles to differentiate each product. How would I do this?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: As an aside, it sound like the IDE and you are 'the tail wagging the dog'.  Don't extend frame, and most of the problems will be solved.

Comment: Have you considered using a `CardLayout` or even a `JTabbedPane` instead of using 4 `JFrame`? It will be a much cleaner looking program, and probably even better performing program

Comment: Hmm no I haven't, let me try it out.

Comment: Try this tutorial for CardLayout or TabbedPane  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html